# Advertencia: Classpath is incomplete. Only syntax errors will be reported

Tags: java

Estoy usando Atom como mi editor de código, he instalado el paquete "atom-ide-ui" y también "ide-java" para poder usar Atom como IDE. Al momento de abir cualquier archivo .java me lanza ésta advertencia

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He configurado también la variable Classpath de mi sistema para que reconozca la ubicación de los archivos .class. No se que error esté ocurriendo, si alguien ha logrado solucionar este problema su ayuda sería excelente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta advertencia se muestra cuando abres un único archivo *Java*, porque en ese momento no se puede configurar ningún classpath, por lo que no se puede proporcionar información sobre otros tipos distintos al *JDK* predeterminado. En ese caso, solo se informan los errores de sintaxis (De lo contrario, obtendría errores de compilación por todos lados.).

Debes abrir una carpeta que contenga un *pom.xml*, o al menos archivos de configuración predeterminados de eclipse, de modo que se pueda establecer una ruta de clases completa y una jerarquía de proyectos.

Es decir, como no se pueden encontrar los archivos de configuración *pom.xml* o de algún IDE como Eclipse, etc. El Classpath está incompleto y solo se informarán de los errores de sintaxis.

Digamos que una forma de construir un proyecto *Java* es utilizar *Maven*, una herramienta de gestión y construcción de proyectos *Java* y su modelo de configuración de construcción basado en *XML* (Pero todo es necesario si quieres trabajar con proyectos, si solo vas a trabajar con un fichero puntual, puedes ignorar la advertencia).

Profundizando más que es el *pom.xml*... 
Project Object Model, es un fichero *XML*, que es la “unidad” principal de un proyecto *Maven*. Contiene información a cerca del proyecto, fuentes, test, dependencias, plugins, version… y los detalles de configuración utilizados por Maven para construir el proyecto.